# Dictionary Replace Strings to Numbers in python

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I want to create a simple cipher in which it uses Phone numbers in place for the letters (input given).

Here is my code below showing what i'm trying to do with just a sample text, but I get an error code of key error: 'L'

```
def main():

    phoneCipher = {'id' : A, 'val': 2},{'id' : B, 'val': 22},{'id' : C, 'val': 222},{'id' : D, 'val': 3},{'id' : E, 'val': 33},{'id' : F, 'val': 333},{'id' : G, 'val': 4},{'id' : H, 'val': 44},{'id' : I, 'val': 444},{'id' : J, 'val': 5},{'id' : K, 'val': 55},{'id' : L, 'val': 555},{'id' : M, 'val': 6},{'id' : N, 'val': 66},{'id' : O, 'val': 666},{'id' : P, 'val': 7},{'id' : Q, 'val': 77},{'id' : R, 'val': 777},{'id' : S, 'val': 7777},{'id' : T, 'val': 8},{'id' : U, 'val': 88},{'id' : V, 'val': 888},{'id' : W, 'val': 9},{'id' : X, 'val': 99},{'id' : Y, 'val': 999},{'id' : Z, 'val': 9999}                  

    #THIS PART IS NOT WORKING BUT IS PART OF WHAT I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DO   
    originalMessage = input("Please input your message to be hidden: ")
    print(originalMessage)
    oMessageSplit = originalMessage.split()
    print(oMessageSplit) 



    sampleList = ['L', 'O', 'L']

    phoneCipherDict = dict((x['id'], x['val']) for x in phoneCipher)
    listCiphered = [phoneCipherDict[x] for x in sampleList]

    print(listCiphered)


main()
```

**My analysis and Feedback needed:** 
I believe this seems to be something wrong with maybe its not an integer vs an actual string. If there is no possible way to do this, could someone point me in the right direction to what method to use for something like this?

Comment: `phoneCipherDict` looks like...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
phoneCipher = {'id' : 'A', 'val': 2},{'id' : 'B', 'val': 22},{'id' : 'C', 'val': 222},...
```

The key should be the string `'L'`, just `L` will try to use the value of variable `L` as key.

**Update**

For creating a list from string, use

```
sampleList = list(originalMessage)
```

Comment: right, I see what you did there, It was referring to the wrong Variable! (DUMB SYNTAX! :P ) --- So the question now would be how do I convert an input string into separated letters like my "sampleList" string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `originalMessage.split()`, which will only split `'LOL'` to `['LOL']`.

A simple `list(originalMessage)` is fine. And you don't even need to do that, because `for char in 'LOL'` is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary should look something like this:

```
phoneCipher = {'A': 2, 'B': 22, ...}
```

Comment: How could I formulate my dict() function at the bottom?

Comment: Oops, didn't read this line. OK you build your dict from a list of dicts. That is OK. BUT... why do the letters don't have single quotes around them? Something like `{'id' : 'A', 'val': 2}`

Comment: I'm confused about your implementation. Why do you need a dict() function? If you build your `phoneCipher` in code like Hyperboreus demonstrates above, you can use that instead of making a separate `phoneCipherDict`.

Comment: @AustinMullins the phoneCipherDict is actually a variable to convert a sample string : sampleList = ['L', 'O', 'L'] --- I named it phoneCipherDict as to eventually use the input from a user to the variable originalMessage.